# Contains looks not working in jenkin pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

In Jenkin pipeline, I read a file and save that to a variable.
Then using the contains(), I wanted to verify whether a particular string exits in the variable.
Actually, it exists but the code is not getting into if block.

Any idea? I can print the entrie file as string content hence string assignment from file read also working . Some issue with contains logic .Please provide your thoughts..

```
pipeline { 
    
    agent any
    
    stages {
    
        stage('read prop file') {
                steps {  
                    echo "1"
                    powershell 'C:\\JenKin_Jobs\\NetUSeIDrive.bat'
                    script {
                  
                         env.filename="C:/Temp/JenkinConsoleLog/$JOB_NAME/GenerateSQA_138.log"
                         env.logtostring=readFile(file: filename)
                        //echo "${env.logtostring}"
                        if (("${env.logtostring}".contains('Reelase is 861'))) {
                            echo "Match found "
                        }   
                    }
                }
        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a typo? Your `Reelase` should't be `Release`?